# Custom Messages Won't Build

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosmake, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using rosmake and fuerte.

`rosbuild_genmsg` is uncommented in the CMakeLists.txt.

Running `rosmake` in the package doesn't create a `msg_gen` folder or the messages. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong....

`No Make file in package my_msgs`

---

In a later project which uses the messages:

`fatal error: my_msgs/MyMsg.h`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74878/custom-messages-won%27t-build/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2013-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I forgot that you needed the custom Makefile in ROS:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile for more information (why is there's no cpp version, i dunno)

More specifically, your Makefile needs to be:

```
include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
```

---

Originally posted by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) with karma: 296 on 2013-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0